# getting "Thank you for creating with WordPress. Version 3.4.2" while trying to edit a page or post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When i try to edit the post or page in my admin,it shows me "**Thank you for creating with WordPress. Version 3.4.2**".
So,i can't able to perform any editing,can perform only quick edit.
Please help,its urgent.Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even a small hint will be of great help to me.

Comment: Can you give us a small hint as to what the footer on the admin page as to do with the ability to edit?

Comment: But,i am getting this message when i click the edit link of the page or post in admin section.

Comment: i have given the screenshots above.Please check it out.

Comment: Anybody help.i can't able to proceed my site without solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted and replaced wp-admin folder of my wordpress folder.Then, everything went smooth.